# Como puedo hacer que un boton tipo submit , tambien pueda llamar a una funcion adicional que no se puede incluir en archivo del form

Tags: jquery, botón, submit

Tengo el siguiente boton

```html
<button type="submit" name="btnCotejar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCotejar"  disabled="disable" >Cotejar</button>
```

el cual al hacer clic en el se realiza el submit del form :

```html
<form id="cotejarBien" method="POST"  action="bienesCotejados.php">
```

ejecutando sin problema las acciones indicadas en el archivo bienesCotejados.php,  pero ocupo que lleve a cabo otra acción la cual no me funciona en el archivo mencionado.  Existe alguna manera que al hacer clic en el botón haga el submit y se pueda cargar una funcion en javascript o un Ajax ?

Comment: Probaste con Javascript? o JQuery? Con Jquery solo estableces la propiedad onclick y puedes ejecutar lo que tu estimes conveniente...

Comment: si estaba pensando en añadir un  onclick al button pero esto no bloquea el submit ?,  incluso ahorita me quede pensando si no seria mas conveniente hacer un onclick y dentro de un archivo.php realizar la llamada a los dos archivos que procesarian los datos

Comment: puedes agregar un atributo dentro de tu etiqueta form llamada onsubmit="return myfunction();", lo que te hace es que se ejecuta un bloque de codigo javascript y dependiendo el resultado devuelves un true o un false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías meter un `onclick="myFunction()"` en tu botón

```
<button type="submit" name="btnCotejar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCotejar"  disabled="disable" onclick="function()" >Cotejar</button>
```

Y en la parte de tu javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    //acciones
}
```

De igual forma podrías modificar tu `<form>`, donde metes la propiedad onsubmit

```
<form id="cotejarBien" method="POST" onsubmit="return myFunction()"  action="bienesCotejados.php" >
```

Comment: ok Isai Maldonado & Ian Stuardo voy  intentarlo así como me comentan y ver que resultado me da, les comento mas tarde que sucedio.

Comment: La buena noticia es que el form sigue funcionando sin problema, la mala es que no carga las acciones indicadas en la funcion....sigo en la lucha ;)

Comment: ¿Y si todo lo haces dentro de tu javascript? Para mas fácil. Agregando lo que ya hiciste checa desde consola y escribe `console.log("prueba");`. Esto dentro de tu función para verificar si esta entrando. Y revisa desde el navegador. Posiblemente le falta algo a lo que tienes.